# PHP SDK Facebook, read private groups

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-group

I would like to read the group names where the user is member.

```
$groups = $facebook->api('/me/groups');
```

Doesn't work for me, it just returns me an empty array. Other things like `/me/albums` work fine?
Is it possible, that I can't read private groups?
I would like to write a Dropbox invite system for students who are in this one group. Everything works, but I can't read if the user is in the specific group or not.

Can you help me?

Comment: solved it... I had to delete the app in facebook and accept the auth dialog again. There were no rights to use the groups.

Comment: Answer yourself in detail so that it'd help others.